# ExtJS loading panels repetition

Tags: extjs, panel, loading

In my website, in order to load diferent pages (to be multipage website) I have a main panel that has the id 'content-panel'.
When I want to load a diferent page I have a javascript function that is called 'loadPage' that loads the page (panel) that I want to the 'content-panel'.
But the page that I want to load has to have this code:

```
Ext.require(['*']);
Ext.onReady(function() {
    ...
    var panel = Ext.Cmp('content-panel');
    panel.add(loginPanel);
    panel.layout.setActiveItem(loginPanel);
    panel.doLayout();
    panel.setLoading(false);
});
```

In this case it is loading the page/panel that is `loginPanel`, that is defined inside `Ext.onReady`
For me this is fine, I don't know of any other way of my website being multi-page.
But everytime that I want to go to a page it loads that page to the 'content-panel', even if it already been loaded before. I want a way to only add the page to 'content-panel' if it is not inside 'content-panel' items.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the `loadPage`

```
function swap(parent, replacement, url) {
  var alpha = document.querySelector(parent);
  var target = alpha.childNodes[0];
  var omega = document.createElement(replacement);
  omega.src = url;
  omega.type = 'text/javascript';
  alpha.replaceChild(omega, target);
}
function loadPage(panel, toPanel) {
    toPanel.setLoading(true);
    swap('head', 'script', panel);
}
```

it is used like this: `loadPage('Ctl_base/view_admin/mainPage', Ext.getCmp('panel'));`
I'm using CodeIgniter with ExtJS.

**What I have already tried:**
I want to do `panel.add(loginPanel)` only if the `loginPanel` doesn't exist.
I have tried:

```
if(panel.getComponent(loginScreen) == undefined) { panel.add(loginPanel); }
```

and it adds the component even when `panel` already has that component.
I have also tried:

```
function hasComponent(parent, child) {
    parent.items.items.forEach(function(item) {
        if(item == child){
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

if(!hasComponent(panel, loginPanel)) { panel.add(loginPanel); }
```

and it also doesn't work.

Comment: If you want help, you should provide your `loadPage` function.

Comment: @Alexander Updated with the `loadPage`

Comment: I guess you have to try first and come with some non-working code. I don't find any attempt to try (a) adding all page JS files to a growing list instead of replacing, (b) finding already loaded pages in that list, (c) finding the respective component in the `content-panel` items list.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for your patience. I have posted all the things that I have tried and didn't work. Do you know any other way? Or can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: you probably should use the update method on a Ext panel to load html page. Pass true as the 2nd parameter if you have javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to tackle this question by putting and *itemId* on the panel that I want to load, and on `panel.layout.setActiveItem(loginPanel);` I have put `panel.layout.setActiveItem('itemIdOfPanel');`